# Asus Epad emulator In Eclipse

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am developing an application on android 3.1 Honeycomb.  It force-closes on Asus epad.
I don't have an Asus Epad to check why it force-closes, so I want to try it on an Asus epad Emulator.  I updated the ADK for eclipse but it doesn't provide an Asus epad Emulator or add-on for it.

In other words, my main problem is that I want to test my application on an Asus emulator.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Update----

```
       It's showing error on background process & it's a null pointer exception. But now I found another way to do this background code so it must work now.
```

Thanks for all your comment.
Still if any one find out plugin or package or a way to create emulator which work as Asus Epad.

Thank You.

Comment: Do you means that you have received reports from Asus ePad users saying that it crashes and you want to find out why?

Comment: Yes Gallal but now I removed that So It must not crash now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that it the app gets force closed on an actual Asus epad, it will get force closed on the emulator too.

You can try to debug your application using LogCat in Eclipse and look the stacktrace to figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: I agree that there if there was such a thing as an Asus emulator, then it would probably crash as well, but it's not for sure.  It could be a device specific bug.  I doubt it, but it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post details about what exactly does it crash on? You could monitor the logs in DDMS and check the stacktrace to analyze what exactly is it crashing on.

Unless you post specific details about a problem, there's very little I or anyone else could help you out with.

Comment: Sorry Sagar but it has problem in asyn task where is download data in startup but now I don't use that code so problem is solved.
Thank You.